# How to change Bugzilla change privacy notice?

Tags: privacy

How can I change the privacy notice in both the site and email messages? My instance is not public facing. I don't like this:

> PRIVACY NOTICE: Bugzilla is an open
>   bug tracking system. Activity on most
>   bugs, including email addresses, will
>   be visible to the public. We recommend
>   using a secondary account or free web
>   email service (such as Gmail, Yahoo,
>   Hotmail, or similar) to avoid
>   receiving spam at your primary email
>   address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change or remove this notice you need to amend the following Template files:

- **create.html.tmpl** located in `\template\en\default\account\`
- **request-new.txt.tmpl** located in `\template\en\default\account\email\`